# Customize Firebase Remote Config

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I want to update the UI of Firebase Remote Config. I tried integrating Retool, but as far as I understand, it doesn't allow me to configure remote settings. Do you have any recommendations for me? How can I edit Remote Config, or what steps can I take to achieve this?

I couldn't find any solution for it. I used Retool but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to explore other alternatives for remote config that have better UI and easily allows full JSON with automatic version control. We have found a great one recently called "Joystick" that is really robust, and used it with some web and mobile game projects. The team is responsive on Discord. Take a look here: https://www.getjoystick.com/features